# Animating Mask Position with Angular 2+

Tags: javascript, css, angular, animation

I'm having trouble animating the mask-position property with angular's animation library and I'm hoping someone can point out where I am going wrong.

I know this works:

```
 @keyframes maskWipe{
     from {mask-position: 100% 0;}
     to {mask-position: 0 0;}
 }
```

But when I try to convert it to angular the animation just **'pops'** when it's done instead of animates.

This is my current animation in angular:

```
animations: [
    trigger('slideInOut', [
      state('slideIn', style({
        webkitMaskPosition: "0 0"
      })),
      state('slideOut', style({
        webkitMaskPosition: "100% 0"
      })),
      transition('slideIn => slideOut', [
        animate('2s', keyframes([
          style({webkitMaskPosition: '0 0'}),
          style({webkitMaskPosition: "100% 0"})
        ]))
      ]),
      transition('slideOut => slideIn', [
        animate('2s', keyframes([
          style({webkitMaskPosition: "100% 0"}),
          style({webkitMaskPosition: "0 0"})
        ]))
      ]),
    ]),
  ],
```

note: I had to use webkitMaskPosition since I'm using chrome and chrome converts mask-position to webkit-mask-position.

[Edit]: forgot to remove the commented out stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course I figure it out shortly after posting this.

Anyways, for some reason you need to add the additional transition to your css like so

```
transition: mask-position 2s linear;
```

I'll just leave this up in case other people happen upon this post.